# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy tratando de generar un codigo automaticamente para mi formulario y me salen los siguientes errores:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\AppServ\www\vetsoft_1\consult_pet\index.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\AppServ\www\vetsoft_1\consult_pet\index.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in
>   C:\AppServ\www\vetsoft_1\consult_pet\index.php on line 8

Espero puedan ayudarme, aquí mi código. Gracias.

```
<?php
include_once('../code/connection/index.php');
$consu = $con->query("SELECT * FROM consulta ORDER BY idpet DESC");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($consu);
$rowid = $consu->fetch_assoc();
$codigo = sprintf("%06d", $rowid['idpet']+1);
$prefijo = "CNS";
$codconsul = $prefijo."-".$codigo;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Adjunta tu código o no te vamos a poder ayudar.

Comment: Hola Tiberius, acabo de corregir mi consulta y adjunte mi código. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Parece que no te hace bien la query, puedes incluir la conexion

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include_once('../code/connection/index.php');
$consu = $con->query("SELECT * FROM consulta ORDER BY idpet DESC");
$total = consu->num_rows;
$rowid = $consu->fetch_assoc();
$codigo = sprintf("%06d", $rowid['idpet']+1);
$prefijo = "CNS";
$codconsul = $prefijo."-".$codigo;
$con->close();
?>
```

No mezcles el *Estilo orientado a objetos* y el *Estilo por procedimientos*.Usa `$consu->num_rows`y `$con->close()`.Si has cerrado la conexión en el `index.php` eso es lo que te da todos esos errores.